# Cant get a modal to work in HandlebarsJs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js

I am learning Handlebars JS for a JS course I am at. But I am having a lot of trouble understanding them. Right Now I need to do the following:

A collage of images using handlebars and when I click on 1 picture I open a modal with the picture I clicked on.

I already got the collage working, but the modal part is really getting frustrating.

This is the data structure

```
 var context = {
  class : [
    {
      type : "Reptiles",
      animals : [
        {
          image1 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/76/Coast_Garter_Snake.jpg/500px-Coast_Garter_Snake.jpg",
          image2 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Nerodia_sipedon_shedding.JPG/440px-Nerodia_sipedon_shedding.JPG",
          name : "Snake",
          description : "Snakes are elongated, ....."
        },
        {
          image1 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Crocodilia_collage.jpg/600px-Crocodilia_collage.jpg",
          image2 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3e/Caiman_crocodilus_Tropicario_2.JPG/440px-Caiman_crocodilus_Tropicario_2.JPG",
          name : "Crocodilia",
          description : "The Crocodilia ..."
        },
        {
          image1 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Bartagame_fcm.jpg/500px-Bartagame_fcm.jpg",
          image2 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Lizard_in_Yemen.JPG/440px-Lizard_in_Yemen.JPG",
          name : "Lizard",
          description : "Lizards are a ...."
        },
        {
          image1 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/Chelonia_mydas_is_going_for_the_air.jpg/440px-Chelonia_mydas_is_going_for_the_air.jpg",
          image2 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/Turtle3m.JPG/500px-Turtle3m.JPG",
          name : "Turtle",
          description : "Turtles are reptiles ......"
        },
      ]
```

This is my script Template for the collage

```
<script id="collage" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="row">
          {{#each class}}
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            {{#each animals}}
            <img src="{{image1}}" class="collage2 thumbnail1 hidden-xs" data-id="{{@index}}">
            <img src="{{image2}}" class="collage2 thumbnail2 hidden-xs" data-id="{{@index}}">
            {{/each}}
          </div>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
</script>
```

This is my script template for the modal

```
<script id="modal-container" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="imageModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{name}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="{{image1}}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</script>
```

Finally this is my modal JS

```
$('.thumbnail1').click(function(event){
  var imageNumber = $(this).data("id");
  var theTemplateScript = $('#modal-container').html();
  var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
  var theCompiledHtml = theTemplate(context.animals.image1[imageNumber]);
  $('#modal-container').html(theCompiledHtml);
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: This would be the complete project. It is quite small  https://github.com/orozcorp/Assign

Answer (score 0):

You are navigating the object hierarchy incorrectly

```
$('.thumbnail1').click(function (event) {
     var imageNumber = $(this).data("id");
     var parent = $(this).data("parent");
     var theCompiledHtml = theTemplate(context.class[parent].animals[imageNumber]);
     $('#myModal').html(theCompiledHtml);
     $("#myModal").modal('show');
 });
```

You would also require the parent index

```
<script id="collage" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="row">
          {{#each class}}
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            {{#each animals}}
            <img src="{{image1}}" class="collage2 thumbnail1 hidden-xs" data-id="{{@index}}" data-parent="{{@../index}}">
            <img src="{{image2}}" class="collage2 thumbnail2 hidden-xs" data-id="{{@index}}" data-parent="{{@../index}}">
            {{/each}}
          </div>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s4casjta/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help,  but I keep getting this .
handlebars.js:2003 Uncaught Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined
compile @ handlebars.js:2003
hb.compile @ handlebars.js:3054
(anonymous function) @ test.js:27

Comment: I copied an pasted the link into my file and test.js 27 is    var templ = Handlebars.compile($('#collage').html());

Comment: I added $( document ).ready(function() {  at the top, now the error is gone but the modal doesnt appear  this is the Gist  https://gist.github.com/orozcorp/85e71c66aa5a33ed992c